# access denied when saving a file.exe to my documents

Tags: c#, byte, access-denied

Hi I want to create a program that saves a File to my documents\test.
The file is .exe. For some unknown reason I get an access denied error, when i tested the program trying to save .txt file (using StreamWriter) the program worked without any problems.
Please help me fellas.

The folowing code throws an error

```
byte[] myfile = Properties.Resources.WallPaper;
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string path2 = path + @"\" + "test";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path2, myfile);
```

The folowing code works fine when saving a .txt file

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string path2 = path + @"\" + "test";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path2 + @"\" + "text.txt");
```

Comment: can you post the exception that you are getting so that we have a better picture

Comment: unauthorizedAccessExepetion - Access to the path 'C:\Users\michael\Documents\test' is denied

Answer (score 2):

Your two examples are not the same.  Your first example does not work because `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` has already created the directory named `test`.  You can't overwrite that directory as if it were a file. In order to make your example 1 behave like example two:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path2)
File.WriteAllBytes(path2 + @"\" + "text.txt", myfile)
```

Comment: I don't understand why... when I try to save the file to D it workes fine

Comment: @misha312 writing a file within a directory is not the same as writing a file over an existing directory. Just as an exercise so you can see my point, create a file (manually, not through your program) named `Test`, and try to copy and paste that `Test` file into a folder that already has a directory named `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

i've never tried to write in an exe file, but you've already tried setting permissions? i don't know if in c# exisist some method that do it, but surely exist "exec", so you could use it to send chmod command